# Should I include node modules in my library bundle?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js, rollup

I'm developing a library of React components. This library is used by several internal NextJs projects.

For reasons of compatibility with NextJs, this library needs to be transpiled into CommonJs at some point.

The problem is that some of my library's npm dependencies don't handle CommonJS. This is the case with swiper, for example.

So I have two options:

- Either I declare the npm dependencies as peerDependencies, and it will be up to each consumer of my library to transpile them correctly. This makes the bundle of my library lighter, but it creates a lot of configuration constraints in each project (for NextJs but also for Jest, for example).
- Or I include the npm dependencies in my bundle, which seems to me to be an anti-pattern, but it would allow me to expose CJS and MJS: the consumers of my library have virtually nothing to do.

I can also envisage a mix of the two: I ignore all the dependencies that manage CommonJs and ES Modules, and I only transpose those that are necessary.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

We have the same situation - we have one Next.js app that depends on a core library that has potentially ESM modules. I recommend do NOT bundle your dependencies, though. Your downstream apps might have the same dependencies, and now you will end up loading them twice. And you probably already this issue anyway with other 3rd party dependencies (that have ESM dependencies). Just add them to your list of `transpilePackages` in `next.config.js`: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/transpilePackages. We are also using next/jest which seems to pick up the configuration too and it seems to work. The only caveat is that I found we have to transpile `@babel/runtime` but only when jest is running or else it blows up the main app.

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  transpilePackages: ['@acme/ui', 'lodash-es'],
}
 
module.exports = nextConfig
```